# Erro após update do WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Ontem fiz Update a todos os Plugins e ao WordPress core (4.0) do meu site.

Inclusive fiz alguns Posts, portanto, estava tudo ok.

Hoje, dá-me este erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_category_id() in
>   /home/vertical/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/VideoTheme/VideoThemeRes/index.php
>   on line 6

Já tentei correr o backup através do UpdraftPlus Backup, mas está a falhar!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Não precisavas criar uma nova pergunta, bastava editar a outra e fazer a tradução. Não, os erros dos programas não precisam ser traduzidos, basta colocá-los como citação, exatamente como você fez. Entenda que a tradução é justamente para ajudar você a conseguir mais chances de respostas para seu problema.

Comment: Verificou esta função lá no arquivo `index.php`?

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está acontecendo na função get_category_id dentro do seu functions.php .. copie essa função no post para verificar o erro!

Answer (score 1):

Já tive a resolução deste problema há uns meses, mas deixo aqui a resposta para o caso deste problema surgir a mais alguem.

Parece que os nomes das funções mudaram neste update, e algo terá corrido mal no update que fez com que elas não se alterassem.

Neste caso:

get_category_id() -> [get_cat_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID)

Deixo também outra função em que isto me aconteceu:

ds_get_excerpt() -> [get_the_excerpt()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt)